# PostgreSQL: Syntax for query nested json array

Tags: json, postgresql

I've recently discovered the  PostgreSQL can be used store JSON
before I import loads of data I need to understand how to retrieve it in particular the nested objects

This [postgresql tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/) is a good starting point but doesn't really explain how to query nested json array

In the sample below I need to select the codes -> code where codes -> level: 1 (adminCode1_iso) is related to adminName1  and if it exists codes -> level: 2 is related to adminName2

```
    CREATE TABLE gn_json (
   id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   info json NOT NULL
);
comment on table gn_json is 'How PG holds json';
insert into gn_json (info)
VALUES ('{
"adminCode2": "C3",
"codes": [
{
"code": "ENG",
"level": "1",
"type": "ISO3166-2"
},
{
"code": "CAM",
"level": "2",
"type": "ISO3166-2"
}
],
"adminCode3": "12UE",
"adminName4": "Yelling",
"adminName3": "Huntingdonshire",
"adminCode1": "ENG",
"adminName2": "Cambridgeshire",
"distance": 0,
"countryCode": "GB",
"countryName": "United Kingdom",
"adminName1": "England",
"adminCode4": "12UE085"
}',
'{
"codes": [
{
"code": "81",
"level": "1",
"type": "ISO3166-2"
}
],
"adminCode1": "63",
"distance": 0,
"countryCode": "TH",
"countryName": "Thailand",
"adminName1": "Krabi"
}');


select info ->> 'countryName' as countryName,info ->> 'countryCode' as countryCode,
info ->> 'adminName1' as adminName1, info ->> 'adminCode1' as adminCode1,
info ->> 'adminName2' as adminName2, info ->> 'adminCode2' as adminCode2,
info ->'codes->0->' -> 'code' as adminCode1_iso,
info ->'codes->1->' -> 'code' as adminCode2_iso
FROM gn_json;
```

Edit Expected outcome

```
countryname countrycode adminname1  admincode1  adminname2  admincode2  admincode1_iso  admincode2_iso
United Kingdom  GB  England ENG Cambridgeshire  C3  ENG CAM
Thailand    TH  Krabi   63  NULL    NULL    81  NULL
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: it's recommended to use `jsonb` over `json` these days.

Comment: Please show us the result that you want.

Comment: If you're using PG12+ you could look into using [jsonpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH)

Comment: Hi i've edited  Expected outcome

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you show me the syntax for jsonb?
@Marth Yes  I'm using PG12 
`info ->> '$.codes[0].code' as adminCode1_iso = null`